# Exception jstz library using

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

I am using `gwt highcharts` and I want to get client timezone calling jsni method from `jstimezoneDetect` in my client java code:

I bind it to my html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jstz-1.0.4.min.js"></script>
```

and call this on client:

```
    static native String getClientTZ() /*-{
    var tz = jstz.determine();
     return tz.name();
}-*/;
```

then I am calling it on page loading:

```
private String clientTimeZone;
pulic UI{
    clientTimeZone=getClientTZ();
....
```

but I'm gettin these error:

`com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (ReferenceError) @UI::getClientTZ()([]): 'jstz' is undefined`

Please any suggestions, what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the browsers console (IE F12, Firefox Tools -> WebDeveloper -> Network) and check if that file is loaded once you access the page.

Comment: a have the jstz is undefined problem still, what can i do?

Answer (score 1):

Got same problem and i resolved it by adding *$wnd* :

```
  private native String getTimeZone() /*-{
    return $wnd.jstz.determine().name();
  }-*/;
```